# How to do Multiline chip group in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image: How to get a layout like this in Jetpack compose?]

So, I've created a Chip composable and using it in a LazyRow like this:

```
LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ){
   items.forEach { it ->
            item {
                CustomChip(
                    item = it,
                    isSelected = it == currentItem,
                    onItemChanged = {
                        onItemChanged(it)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
}
```

But, I want to attain a layout like the above mentioned image. I.e, If number of chips reaches end of screen, then the new chips should come in new line.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update.** Now you can use system [`FlowRow`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow):

```
val words = LoremIpsum(10).values.first()
    .split(" ", "\n")

FlowRow(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(7.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(7.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
) {
    words.forEach { word ->
        Text(
            word,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Gray, shape = CircleShape)
                .padding(vertical = 3.dp, horizontal = 5.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

**Original answer.** If you are interested in building something like this yourself, you can do it with `Layout`:

```
@Composable
fun ChipVerticalGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    spacing: Dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        var currentRow = 0
        var currentOrigin = IntOffset.Zero
        val spacingValue = spacing.toPx().toInt()
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

            if (currentOrigin.x > 0f && currentOrigin.x + placeable.width > constraints.maxWidth) {
                currentRow += 1
                currentOrigin = currentOrigin.copy(x = 0, y = currentOrigin.y + placeable.height + spacingValue)
            }

            placeable to currentOrigin.also {
                currentOrigin = it.copy(x = it.x + placeable.width + spacingValue)
            }
        }

        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = placeables.lastOrNull()?.run { first.height + second.y } ?: 0
        ) {
            placeables.forEach {
                val (placeable, origin) = it
                placeable.place(origin.x, origin.y)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val words = LoremIpsum(10).values.first()
    .split(" ", "\n")

ChipVerticalGrid(
    spacing = 7.dp,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(7.dp)
) {
    words.forEach { word ->
        Text(
            word,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Gray, shape = CircleShape)
                .padding(vertical = 3.dp, horizontal = 5.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this approach. But both solutions don't support scrollability.

Comment: Okay: it is easy to get.  Just add a `.verticalScroll(scrollState)` to the modifier of the flowLayout

Comment: Your original answer was very useful & customizable, thanks!

Comment: How to make layout RTL in original answer??

Comment: Also verticalArrangement  doesn't work in update answer.

Comment: @SadeghJ `verticalArrangement` works fine to me in the update answer. I don't have enough RTL knowledge to support it in the original one

Answer (score 4):

As of 10th of November 2022 until they advice otherwise, Google engineers recommend using

```
FlowRow {
    // row contents
}

FlowColumn {
    // column contents
}
```

From https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/flowlayout

Android Dev Summit 22 https://youtu.be/TqbzXC1xtko?t=5146

Answer (score 1):

**[2023] Google Official:**

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow

```
FlowRow(
    modifier = modifier,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
) {
    items.forEach { it ->
        item {
            CustomChip(
                item = it,
                isSelected = it == currentItem,
                onItemChanged = {
                    onItemChanged(it)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```