# Jetpack Compose maxRows Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have a requirement do display a variable number of variable-width elements up to a maximum of 2 rows.

For example I might have:

```
                         |
                         V End of row
AA | BBBB | C | DDDDDDDD
EEEE | FF | GGGG
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH (too wide to fit on row 2 therefore ignored)
```

I'm not worried about reordering the elements to maximise the amount displayed but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I feel like it should be a custom Layout but I can't see any examples that I can easily adapt to my purposes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction (hopefully with code examples)?

Comment: I just discovered the accompanist FlowRow which does nearly all of my requirements, it just doesn't seem to have a max rows constraint.

Comment: check out how you can do a simple version of `FlowRow` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979204/3585796) which may be easier to modify to your needs